# Import multiple photos to parse.com database

Tags: import, parse-platform, photo, pffile

I'm trying to build an navigation app with place location and its photos.

I have 200 spot location names (String), its location (GeoPoints), and its image (JPG).
is it possible to upload the database including the image instantly?

I only managed to upload the String and GeoPoints database using json, but still can't do it for the image file.

anyway,
clicking one by one is definitely not an option. I got 200 images and still counting. It might reach 500 or more in several weeks.

thank you in advance,

Comment: This would take a long time if you were doing it manually via the data browser. If you data is already in JSON format, with each item pointing to the file on a local file system (or a URL). It should be easy enough to write an application in the language of your choice to automatically upload the files. When I need to seed my Parse applications with some data, I usually use Python and the REST API, but with JS/C#/Objective-C SDKs, you have lots of options.

Comment: do you have any links or something for me to study about it?

Comment: What language are you using? And can I confirm you are trying to seed your initial data set? (Ie this isn't something you would have a client app doing everyday)

Comment: yes. I'm trying to set my initial data only. User basically only see the photos. They don't have to upload anything.

I'm start learning with swift actually. But if you have other language, I will try to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

how large are the images?

if you can scale (photos) them down a little bit and if you have multiple threads on the httpclient being used with parse.com then you should be able to saturate the WIFI / ISP bandwidth available to your device.

ie if you've got 10 Mb available upstream to the ISP then you ought to be able to optimize the use of multiple , async connections up so that you are pushing close to 10Mb of photos to parse.com.

It probably wont help much ( parse - android example ) but this was precisely the target of [this question](https://www.parse.com/questions/rest-api-or-android-sdk-for-real-time-messaging-and-data).

63 photos ( each 70K in sz ) upload in 3 seconds total .

Comment: Thanks for your idea. do you know how to do it from PC? using javascript maybe?